# Display categories with number of posts

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a blog. I have 2 tables, one for `posts` and the other for `categories`.

I want to display the category name, category date and the number of posts in each category. I have problems to display the number of posts in each category.
In `posts` table I have a column called `cat_id` which is equal to `category.id`

I have these 2 MySQL queries:

```
mysql_query("select Count(posts.id) as NumberOfPosts, cat_id from posts group by cat_id");
```

And

```
mysql_query("select name, date from categories");
```

I don't know how to have combine these two queries into one query. I'm using PHP.

Comment: Come on.  Bit more effort required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `join`:

```
SELECT name, date, NumberOfPosts
FROM   categories c
JOIN   (SELECT   cat_id, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPosts
        FROM     posts
        GROUP BY cat_id) p ON c.id = p.cat_id
```

EDIT:
To include categories with no posts, you could use a `left join` instead of regular `join`. You just need to handle the `null`s you'd get for `NumberOfPosts`, e.g., by using `coalesce`:

```
SELECT      name, date, COALESCE(NumberOfPosts, 0) AS NumberOfPosts
FROM        categories c
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT   cat_id, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPosts
             FROM     posts
             GROUP BY cat_id) p ON c.id = p.cat_id
```

Comment: and how to echo the cat_id and the NumberOfposts?

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working i just had to add an 'id' in the beginning of the query - then the query look like this:    SELECT id, name, date, NumberOfPosts
FROM   categories c
JOIN   (SELECT   cat_id, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPosts
        FROM     posts
        GROUP BY cat_id) p ON c.id = p.cat_id

Comment: But that query displays only the categories  containing posts. What if a category is just added and has 0 posts. Is there any way to display them too?